# If I do not travel to the United States after receiving an H1B visa, will there be any consequences?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, h1b-visas

I am currently in India and I recently got my H1B visa stamped through a consultancy, which offered me a job in New Jersey with an annual salary of $106,000. However, I have now received a better offer in India with a very good package in Bangalore (45 LPA), so I have decided not to travel to the US.

What are the consequences of not using this H1B visa?